# Having an HTTP error 500 after migrating a website

Tags: php, apache

Guys I'm having an HTTP error 500 after trying to migrate another site to an Ubuntu 16.04LTs virtual server. My other websites are working in these server but this one gives and error when I'm trying to access in my browser.

I looked inside my `error.log` and found this:

```
[Tue Dec 05 14:18:07.678856 2017] [:error] [pid 14267] [client 121.97.63.220:61421] PHP Fatal error:  'continue' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in /var/www/html/brainsmartsuccess.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/inlinks/inlinks.php on line 476
```

I've set the permissions for the specific files as stated in the logs but having no success on removing the HTTP error 500.

Any help is much appreciated!

-Cody

Comment: Any help would help a lot

Answer (score -1):

The error almost answers your question. Rename the folder for the plugin inlinks and the site should be restored. You may have to clear your browser's cache. Once that is done you can work out the PHP error which is likely the result of using PHP versions on your dev and live server that are a couple of releases apart. I'd guess you can remove the break in the offending plugins code at public_html/wp-content/plugins/inlinks/inlinks.php on line 476 and it will run but I wouldn't trust it not to have a nasty security hole or another fatal error waiting to popup. I would just replace the function of the inlinks plugin completely to save time and be safe.

Comment: The this is, i did rename that plugin and all the folders that's needed. Still it gave me the error. Makes no sense

Comment: try renaming the entire plugins folder and if you still get a 500 error you should check for a permission error files need 644 and folder 755 or check your wp-config.php for an error. those are the two places I would check first. If the error goes away then you know it is a plugin. Revert the plugin folder name and then rename each plugin until you find the one with the issue.